# Select previous row for each entry in Table/List

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Row       TimeStamp
____|________________________
1   | 2015-01-01 12:00:01.000
2   | 2015-01-01 12:00:02.000
3   | 2015-01-01 12:00:03.000
4   | 2015-01-01 12:00:04.000
5   | 2015-01-01 12:00:05.000
6   | 2015-01-01 12:00:06.000
7   | 2015-01-01 12:00:07.000
8   | 2015-01-01 12:00:08.000
9   | 2015-01-01 12:00:09.000
```

Selecting the previous row's TimeStamp has been a rather simple task

e.g.

```
SELECT  MAX([TimeStamp])
FROM [MyTable] 
WHERE [TimeStamp] < '2015-01-01 12:00:02.000'
```

gets `2015-01-01 12:00:01.000` as expected.

However I'm having some trouble selecting a list of TimeStamps from multiple preceding rows.

For example, if I wanted to get the timestamps of the preceding rows for Row >= 3 && <= 6

```
(i.e. 
    SELECT [TimeStamp]
    FROM [MyTable] 
    WHERE [Row] >= 3 AND [Row] <= 6

    =>

    TimeStamps     
    2015-01-01 12:00:03.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:04.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:05.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:06.000
)
```

How would I go about getting the preceding TimeStamp for *each* of these result rows?

```
(i.e. 
    TimeStamps                   
    2015-01-01 12:00:02.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:03.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:04.000
    2015-01-01 12:00:05.000
)
```

I've seen quite a few solutions related to lag/lead, but my usage of SQLServer 2008 is difficult to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.TimeStamp,
    (
     SELECT MAX(t1.TimeStamp)
        FROM MyTable t1
        WHERE t1.Row < t.Row
    ) AS PrevTimeStamp
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.Row >= 3 AND t.Row <= 6
```

This would give you side-by-side columns, one current and one previous.

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id, max(a.timestamp)
from mytable a join mytable b 
on a.id < b.id
where b.id between --desired values
group by b.id
```

Here is a fiddle with sample data: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebce1/27)

will this work for you? This will `join` on all the previous rows and then picks up the `max` timestamp which would always be the value of the previous row, assuming timestamp column is ordered ascending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to number rows, and look up the previous one with a `left join`:

```
; with  numbered as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by TimeStamp) as rn
        ,       *
        from    YourTable
        )
select  cur.TimeStamp
,       prev.TimeStamp
from    numbered cur
left join
        numbered prev
on      prev.rn + 1 = cur.rn
where   cur.row between 3 and 6
```